# Hooking up express into React webpack project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

I'm attempting to add express to my React project in order to start connecting to databases to store form information.  I'm pretty lost on how to set this up.  Currently I'm using webpack and creating a dev server that renders out my React view.  My stack looks like...

Webpack - React - Babel - SASS.

React Router is currently handling all of my nav links to my page and I have it pretty much running the way I want it on my localhost.  So now I have to figure out a way to handle the contacts form data and put it into the mongoDB I have created for the project.  In the past I made an app using express w/handlebars & mongoose to connect into mongoDB, so I thought lets add express to the project!  I just have no clue how to connect a server into my react app, and how it will conflict with webpack-dev-server and what not.

I installed express-react-router-views express mongoose - basically anything I thought that I might need to get my server up and running.

Does anyone know how to link my React project ( the routes ) into the an express server?

My layout with webpack takes all of the JSX and spits it out into a bundle in a public folder with a new index.html and bundle.js.  Everything else (components, router, sass) lives inside my app folder.  So far I created a server folder inside my app folder (should it be outside?) and made a server.js file.  Now I'm quite lost on how to hook this all up.

server.js file

```
import express from 'express';
import { Router, Route, Redirect, IndexRoute, Link, hashHistory } from 'react-router'; 
import ExpressReactRouter from 'express-react-router-views';
import routes from '../utils/Routes.js';


var express = require('express');

var app = express();
// Set the engine as .jsx or .js
app.engine('.jsx', ExpressReactRouter.engine({
  routes: routes
}));

// Set the view engine as jsx or js
app.set('view engine', 'jsx');

// Set the custom view
app.set('view', ExpressReactRouter.view);

app.get('/public/', function(req, res) {
  // You can replace req.url with the view path that you've set on the routes file
  res.render(req.routes);
});
```

webpack.config.js file...

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');


var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './app/App.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public',
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig],
  devServer: {
       inline:true,
       contentBase: './public',
       port: 3333
     },
  module: {
    loaders: [{ 
         test: /\.js$/, 
         exclude: /node_modules/, 
         loader: "babel-loader"
      },
        {
              test: /\.scss$/,
              loader: 'style!css!sass'
            }]
  }
};
```

Comment: it seems like using express w/webpack I'll end up having two localhosts server my website -  which is confusing to me

Answer (score 0):

You can use the match function in "react-router" which can help you use your react routes on the server side. Please take a look at this project, I think it's pretty clear how to use it.

https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/src/server.js#L84